# How to create an array of an array of structs

Tags: c, struct, bison

I am trying to create a symbol table using an array of an array of structs.

Right now I just have an array of structs and it's created like this:

```
#define MAXSIZE 20 /* maximum number of symbols */
#define MAXSCOPE 10 /* maximum number of scope levels */

 struct tableEntry {
 char *name;
 char *args;
 int value;
 int scope;
 char *type;
 int used;
 } tableEntry [MAXSIZE];
```

It works, but I want to make something like this:

```
symbolTable[MAXSCOPE].tableEntry[MAXSIZE]
```

How would I do that?  Does it make sense what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
struct tableEntry symbolTable[MAXSCOPE];
```

and use e.g.

```
symbolTable[scope][entry].value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a 2 dimensional array of structs:

```
// Define the type
typedef struct tableEntry {
    char *name;
    char *args;
    int value;
    int scope;
    char *type;
    int used;
} tableEntry;

// Instantiate a 2D array of this type
tableEntry myArray[MAXSCOPE][MAXSIZE];
```

You can now access individual entries like this:

```
// Initialise 'value' in each entry to 2
int scope=0;
int size=0;
for (; scope < MAXSCOPE; scope++)
{
    for (; size < MAXSIZE; size++)
    {
        myArray[scope][size].value = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to access it that way...

```
#define MAXSIZE 20 /* maximum number of symbols */
#define MAXSCOPE 10 /* maximum number of scope levels */

 struct _table_entry_ {
     char *name;
     char *args;
     int value;
     int scope;
     char *type;
     int used;
};

struct _symbol_table_ {
    _table_entry_ tableEntry[MAXSIZE]; 
}symbolTable[MAXSCOPE];
```

This is how you can access the data

```
symbolTable[1].tableEntry[2].value = 1;
```